# Simple LinkedList

Tags: c#, linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel

I guess this has been made a couple of times by now, but i wanted to take my chance on creating a simple generic linked list in c#.
What do you think ?

This is the main class.

```
public class LinkedList<T>: IEnumerator<T>
{
    private Node<T> head;
    private Node<T> tail;


    public T Current
    {
        get { return myCurrentNode.GetValue(); }
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current => Current;

    private Node<T> myCurrentNode;

    public LinkedList()
    {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }


    public void Add(T value)
    {
        if (head == null && tail == null)
        {
            head = new Node<T>(value);
            tail = head;
            Reset();
            return;
        }

        tail.SetNextNode(new Node<T>(value));
        tail = tail.GetNextNode();
    }

    public void RemoveCurrentNode()
    {
        var node = new Node<T>();
        node.SetNextNode(head);

        while (node.GetNextNode() != myCurrentNode)
        {
            node = node.GetNextNode();
        }

        var nextNode = myCurrentNode.GetNextNode();
        node.SetNextNode(nextNode);

        if (head == myCurrentNode)
        {
            head = nextNode;
        }

        if (tail == myCurrentNode)
        {
            tail = node;
        }

        myCurrentNode = nextNode;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        var nextNode = myCurrentNode.GetNextNode();
        if (nextNode != null)
        {
            myCurrentNode = nextNode;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        myCurrentNode = new Node<T>();
        myCurrentNode.SetNextNode(head);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        myCurrentNode = null;
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }
}
```

Node class.

```
public class Node<T>
{
    private T _value;
    private Node<T> _nextNode;

    public Node()
    {

    }

    public T GetValue()
    {
        return _value;
    }

    public Node(T Value)
    {
        _value = Value;
    }

    public Node<T> GetNextNode()
    {
        return _nextNode;
    }

    public void SetNextNode(Node<T> nextNode)
    {
        _nextNode = nextNode;
    }
}
```

And three unit tests to check my implementation.

```
public class LinkedListTest
{
    private LinkedList.LinkedList<int> linkedList;
    private List<int> initialList;

    [Fact]
    public void LinkedListCanBeEnumerated()
    {
        //arange
        InitializeLinkedList(100);

        //act
        int[] array = new int[100];
        int index = 0;
        while (linkedList.MoveNext())
        {
            array[index++] = (linkedList.Current);
        }

        //assert
        array.ToList().ForEach(i => initialList.Contains(i).ShouldBe(true));
    }

    private void InitializeLinkedList(int howMany)
    {
        linkedList = new LinkedList.LinkedList<int>();
        initialList = Enumerable.Range(1, howMany).ToList();
        initialList.ForEach(i => linkedList.Add(i));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void RemovingCurrentNodeShouldAlterTheList()
    {
        //arange
        InitializeLinkedList(100);

        //act
        linkedList.MoveNext();
        linkedList.RemoveCurrentNode();
        linkedList.Reset();

        int[] array = new int[100];
        int index = 0;
        while (linkedList.MoveNext())
        {
            array[index++] = (linkedList.Current);
        }

        //assert
        array.ToList().ForEach(i => i.ShouldNotBe(1));

    }

    [Fact]
    public void RemovingTailNodeShouldResultInADifferentTailNode()
    {
        //arange
        InitializeLinkedList(3);

        //act
        linkedList.MoveNext();
        linkedList.MoveNext();
        linkedList.MoveNext();

        linkedList.RemoveCurrentNode();
        linkedList.Reset();

        int[] array = new int[3];
        int index = 0;
        while (linkedList.MoveNext())
        {
            array[index++] = (linkedList.Current);
        }

        //assert
        array.ToList().ForEach(i => i.ShouldNotBe(3));
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a new node in the reset to respect the corect implementation of the IEnumerator interface. Check the Remarks section over here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 16):

#### Collection != enumerator

The main problem I see here is that `LinkedList<T>` implements `IEnumerator<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>`. That's the wrong interface, which makes this class quite difficult to use: you now have to manually call `MoveNext()` and `Current`, instead of being able to use `foreach`. This also prevents you from using Linq methods, and you can't do simultaneous enumerations.

`IEnumerable<T>` represents a sequence of items that can be enumerated, such as an array, a (linked) list, or the result of a generator method (`yield`).

`IEnumerator<T>` represents the act of enumeration a collection. Enumerators are rarely used directly - they're usually 'hidden' behind a `foreach` statement (which calls `GetEnumerator` on the given enumerable to obtain an enumerator).

---

The above means that `myCurrentNode` does not belong in this class - it should be part of an enumerator. The same goes for `Current`, `MoveNext`, `Reset` and `Dispose`.

Regarding `RemoveCurrentNode`, it's both cumbersome and inefficient. Cumbersome, because you can't just pass the value (or node) that you want to remove as an argument - you have to look for it by enumerating the list. Inefficient, because once you've found the right node, `RemoveCurrentNode` also has to perform a linear search to find the preceding node.

Take a look at `System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<T>` to get some inspiration. It's a doubly linked list, so not all of its methods are applicable in your case, but it should give you an idea of how to play to the strengths of a linked list.

#### Other notes

- `IEnumerator.Reset` is essentially deprecated. Enumerating a collection again is done by obtaining a new enumerator. Modern enumerators typically throw an exception in `Reset`.
- Note that `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator` is quite easy to implement with `yield`.
- There's no need to initialize `head` and `tail` to `null` - that's their default value already.
- There's also no need for disposal here - there are no unmanaged resources here that require disposal.
- Why does `Node` use Java-style get and set methods instead of properties? I'd expect to see `public T Value { get; }` and `public Node<T> NextNode { get; set; }`.
- Personally I would handle the `head == myCurrentNode` edge-case in `RemoveCurrentNode` without creating an extra node. With or without doesn't make much of a difference in terms of code complexity, so I'd pick the more efficient approach (the one without an extra allocation).
- A `LinkedList(IEnumerable<T> collection)` constructor would be useful.

Comment: Thank you @Pieter, now I understand the reason behind IEnumerator. I would improve this implementation with a IEnumerable instead.